# How/Why does this CSS code work in making my text responsive?

Tags: html, css, font-size, calc

```
font-size: calc(4rem + 1vw);
```

I somewhat understand that the `calc` function makes my font dynamically sized, but

1. I don't understand how `4rem + 1vw` works (what exactly is it doing).
2. I don't understand how `calc` interacts or affects `4rem + 1vw`

Comment: The value 1vw is equal to 1% of the viewport width. As the viewport width changes, so will the font size.

Comment: If you understand what the [rem and vw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units) units represents, and you understand that the [`calc` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) _calculates_ the result of the expression it is passed, it should be self explanatory.

Answer (score 4):

Break it down:

```
font-size: calc(4rem + 1vw);
```

```
1vw
```

[`vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) is "equal to 1% of the width of the viewport's initial containing block". The browser can calculate that to a pixel value.

```
4rem
```

[`rem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Font-relative_lengths) is relative to the font size of the HTML element. The browser can calculate that to a pixel value.

So,

```
calc(4rem + 1vw)
```

[`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) adds those values together and sets the `font-size` property to that value.

Now, I'm saying "pixel value" here, but it could be some intermediate value that has nothing to do with pixels per se, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `rem` and `vw` work kinda the same, but not with the same references. You have to see `rem` and `vw` as pretty much just other metrics.

`rem` is based on your root html font-size. Which means that as long as your html has a font-size of, let's say, 16px, 1rem will equal 16px. If at any point, you change your html font-size, all the `rem` metrics of your css will adapt. It allows for a more uniform render on browsers with different default css values when it has not been set directly by the developer. (For more infos, see [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/))

*So here, as long as you don't change your html font-size, 4rem = 64px.*

Now about `vw`, it works pretty much like we described with rem, but it is based not on a fixed font-size anywhere, but on your window with. Which makes it based on a completely variable data. You can see this variable like this: for a 1000px window, 1px = 0.1vw. So 1vw is 1% of your window width.

*So here, if your window width is 1000px, 1vw = 10px.*

The calc is literally just adding them: 64px + 10px.
At the end, with your code you will have a fixed `4rem` that will always have the same value as long as the html font-size stay the same, and a variable addition of 1vw that will depend on your browser width.

EDIT:

As a last info, because maybe it isn't clear: You don't need `calc`or the `4rem` to make you font-size "responsive". Try with `font-size: 1vw` and it will also be responsive. Your calc will just make the variation based on your device width a smaller part of your final font-size.